# is there any issue about WeakReference on Android?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, weak-references

i want to transfer an Object throw intent ,
but the object doesn't implements Serializable or parcelable.
so i realize it like this:

```
private static Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, WeakReference<Object>>();

public static void saveObjectInIntent(Intent intent, String key,
        Object value) {
    String realKey = randomString();
    map.put(realKey, new WeakReference<Object>(value));
    if (intent != null) {
        intent.putExtra(key, realKey);
    }
}

public static Object getObjectFromIntent(Intent intent, String key) {
    String realKey = intent.getStringExtra(key);
    WeakReference<Object> weak = map.get(realKey);
    if (weak != null) {
        return weak.get();
    }
    return null;
}
```

but i found that even though the activity is finished, the object in weakreference is not recycled by gc.

so i write a test like that:

```
Object obj = new Object();
ObjectTrsnferHelper.saveObjectInIntent(null, "a", obj);
obj = null;
```

the obj is not recycled either.

why ?

---

sorry, there is no probleam.
but i wrote my test code wrong before.

it should be :

```
Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
for (String key : keys) {
    WeakReference<Object> weak = map.get(key);
    if (weak.get() == null) {
        App.log(key + "被清除了");
    }
}
```

i wrote "if(weak==null)" before.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much control in Java over garbage collection. Even if you call System.gc(), you can't expect the garbage collector to have run at the end of the statement.

Usually though, garbage collection occurs at the end of methods. But still, there is no requirement for it to run on each method.

Also, an activity being finished doesn't mean it's gonna be garbage collected right now. Both things are quite different. For instance if you keep a static field and set it to your activity instance (and that's a very bad idea, kids don't do that !!), the activity will never be garbage collected..

But globally, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. If your object is not parcellable nor serializable, you just can't use it inside an intent. Intents are made to resist to garbage collection, they need to be serialized, they are serialized by Android. There is no workaround for that.

Moreover intents are also designed to pass parameters through Inter Process Communication and that can only happen because they are fully serializable.

Really, you can't do what you want to do using that way. If you want to share an object between activities, make it serializable or parcelable. An other option can be to store it in the application class as it can be accessed by both activities using getApplication.

Comment: the class is not writted by me ,so i cann't let it implements parcelable.   i reread my code just now,and found the problem. actually the object in weakreference is recycled by gc.

the test code should be:

weakreference<Object> weak=map.get("key");
if(weak.get()==null){
sysout("it is recycled.");
}
---------------------------------------------
i wrote it like this before:

if(map.get("key")==null){
sysout("it is recycled");
}
-----------------------
that is wrong.


thankn you all the same.

Comment: cann't comment contains newline?